# Navbar stuck to top, margin error?

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, parallax

I've got this problem when i try to stick the navigation bar to the top after i scroll down a little.
I'm also using this [parallax](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) plugin (don't know if this has anything to with the issue).

My problem is that when i enter my website and scroll down to my footer. Then everything inside my footer gets pushed upwards.
When i refresh the page at the bottom the footer is all right (also when i scroll up and down).

So the problem is when i enter the website, and start from the top.

I have two images that displays the issue.

This is how it SHOULD look, everytime i enter the page and scroll down.
Also, this is how it looks when i scroll down, and refresh at the bottom (which is right).
[image]

This is how it DOES look when i enter from start of the page an scroll down.
[image]

I have figured out it has something to do with when i stick the navigation bar to the top. I do this with jQuery, just adding the class `.fixed` to it.
The .fixed class looks like this:

```
.fixed {
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:9999;
}
```

And this is how i do it in jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 350) {
        $('#navigation').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance. I can submit parts of the code if that would help. The website is not online, only local.

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem or an online **minimalistic** working version of the problem. Unfortunately, the information you've given us is not sufficient. If you could put your website online we may be able to help. Try jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.
I wrapped the navbar in another wrapper, and set a height on that wrapper.
Now it works perfect! :)